When can we claim that the training converged?
I've been working for a while in a binary classification problem with different types of neural networks. In this particular case, I'm using an 3-layer MLP with hyperbolic tangent activation in input and hidden layer and sigmoid for the ouput layer.
I decided to use ADAM optimizer, and after some parameter tweaking I managed to obtain consistent training in terms of the accuracy obtained. The look like this 
Just by looking at this plot, and taking into account that if I repeat the training results are really close to each other I would say that the model converged. The thing is that loss plot look as follows

Theoretically we should look to loss validation to decrease at training loss' pace or as similar as possible, but I haven't been able to achieve that in any of my trainings. So, based on the fact that validation accuracy is stable and reasonable (for my task), can I say that training converged?
Any advice, reference or info is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The convergence is just a matter of the training loss curve. Looking at yours, we know that your training converged. Nevertheless, it has a severe overfitting problem and you probably should do something about it, e.g. add dropout.

Hi @noe, thanks for your reply ^^ I guess that you can confirm that my model converged because training's loss curve is stable and close to 0, and the overfitting problem can be seen in the growth of the validation's loss curve, isn't it? In that case, I have the feeling that classification metrics (such as the accuracy or F1-score) are in such a way "independent" of the model convergence.
To sum up, I see that convergence and performance are separated but I feel they shouldn't be. Do you have any book/article that could help me on that? :)

the overfitting problem can be seen in the growth of the validation's loss curve, isn't it? → Yes, classification metrics are in such a way "independent" of the model convergence → No, the metrics will probably not be very good for a model whose training did not converge; the thing is that a model converging does not imply good performance.

the thing is that a model converging does not imply good performance I see @noe ;) I made some new trainings adding dropout to the hidden layer but I'm still facing the overfitting problem. I know that my main impariment is that my dataset is not large enough (300 instances) but I'm trying to apply some data augmentation techniques. Do you know any rule of thumb to 'eyeball' model's architecture basing on the amount of data you have available?
